# How does weava highlighter extension works under the hood?

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors

There's [weava highlighter extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/weava-highlighter-pdf-web/cbnaodkpfinfiipjblikofhlhlcickei?hl=en) which make it possible to highlights articles/pdf and store highlight on the server.

I can't understand how does it keep highlights after the page reloaded. What does need to be stored to find the highlighted section after the page reloaded? I can't store text, because text can be duplicated. CSS selectors not enough too, how does it work?

Tried to debug the extension, but the code is highly uglified and it's difficult to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it stores enough text to describe the beginning and the end of the section to ensure uniqueness, found following traces in the console:

```
"-MI0L15LAX*************": {
            "accessRight": {
                "HZTU1cv32******************": "owner"
            },
            "createDate": 1600971612666,
            "creator": "HZTU1cv32******************",
            "favIconUrl": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196",
            "highlights": {
                "d1311a13-d334-467c-8915-5faf412a689f": {
                    "colorNum": 3,
                    "creator": "HZTU1cv32p******************",
                    "date": 1600972075045,
                    "endStr": "afterthepagereloaded?ican'tsto",
                    "startStr": "tobestoredtofindthehighlighted",
                    "text": "section"
                }
            },
            "title": "html - How does weava highlighter extension works under the hood? - Stack Overflow",
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052135/how-does-weava-highlighter-extension-works-under-the-hood",
            "version": "0.0.3"
        }
```

It isn't perfect, and error-prone (I was able to trick it to highlight the wrong section), but it looks that there's enough for most people.
Another drawback of such an approach, if the article changed a little bit (typo, etc...) the highlights can be lost.